# How do I convert json string into JsonObject and iterate on it? .NET Core 6.0 c#

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, .net-6.0

As in the topic, I'm making a request to an endpoint, which in return gives me a json string. Sample json string (picked up 6 substrings, there is about thousand more):

```
{"probability":0.0062596053,"tagId":"sometagid","tagName":"apple","boundingBox":{"left":0.27482307,"top":0.4361664,"width":0.14311266,"height":0.37521422}},
{"probability":0.0061301645,"tagId":"sometagid","tagName":"apple","boundingBox":{"left":0.0,"top":0.44423538,"width":0.09239961,"height":0.37426883}},
{"probability":0.0059485333,"tagId":"sometagid","tagName":"carrot","boundingBox":{"left":0.037714787,"top":0.0,"width":0.15685204,"height":0.27176687}},
{"probability":0.005887271,"tagId":"sometagid","tagName":"tomato","boundingBox":{"left":0.5249929,"top":0.70379305,"width":0.44499594,"height":0.29620594}},
{"probability":0.0057223,"tagId":"sometagid","tagName":"apple","boundingBox":{"left":0.79498,"top":0.34279144,"width":0.19351125,"height":0.39170527}},
{"probability":0.0056102676,"tagId":"sometagid","tagName":"apple","boundingBox":{"left":0.030394234,"top":0.21933028,"width":0.16375154,"height":0.3037323}},
```

What do I need? I need this string to be splitted into these 6 (+1000) objects (preferably to an array) and I want to pick only these object that contain `probability*100 > 50`.

I've already made a class that contains such values as:

```
public class ResponseJsonNode {
    public double probability { get; set; }
    public string tagId { get; set; }
    public string tagName { get; set; }
    public BoundingBox boundingBox { get; set; }
}
```

And BoundingBox is another class:

```
public class BoundingBox {
    double left { get; set; }
    double top { get; set; }
    double width { get; set; }
    double height { get; set; }
}
```

Reproducible example (well not quite really because i can't post endpoint and key here):

```
using System.Net;
using System.Text.Json;
using ConsoleApp1;


WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("SomeUriEndpoint");
request.Method = "POST";
request.Headers.Add("some key", "some more key");
request.Headers.Add("some content type", "some more content type");
var f = File.Open(args[0], FileMode.Open);
using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    f.CopyTo(ms);
    var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
    request.ContentLength = fileBytes.Length;
    Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
    stream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
    stream.Close();
    //imageStringBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
}
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponseAsync().Result;
string json = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
//JsonObject jo = (JsonObject)json;
List<ResponseJsonNode> jsonNodeList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ResponseJsonNode>>(json);
foreach(ResponseJsonNode rj in jsonNodeList) {
    Console.WriteLine(rj);
}
```

And this gives me an error:

```
The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List
```

This does not work also:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponseAsync().Result;
string json = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
//JsonObject jo = (JsonObject)json;
//List<ResponseJsonNode> jsonNodeList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ResponseJsonNode>>(json);
JsonArray jsonArray = JsonNode.Parse(json).AsArray();
List<ResponseJsonNode> nodes = new List<ResponseJsonNode>();
foreach(JsonObject jo in jsonArray) {
    nodes.Add(new ResponseJsonNode { probability = Convert.ToDouble(jo["probability"]), tagName = (string)jo["tagName"] });
}
var stats = new Dictionary<string, double>();
foreach (ResponseJsonNode rjn in nodes) {
    if (rjn.probability * 100 > 50)
        if (stats.ContainsKey(rjn.tagName)) {
            stats[rjn.tagName]++;
        } else {
            stats[rjn.tagName] = 1;
        }
}
```

Throws an error: `System.InvalidOperationException: The node must be of type 'JsonArray'`

I have tried to parse it with numerous tutorials but every one of them seems deprecated or does not work (example shown above). So what is the best possible solution for converting json string into a iterable JsonObject? (Not specificly JsonObject class that is in c# libraries but something that i could iterate on)

Comment: The JSON you're showing is a single object, not an array.  Why are you trying to make it into a `List<ResponseJsonNode>`?  What is the goal for that?

Comment: Yes, I might have misunderstood use of this class. I want this specific json string called `string json` to be put into array so that I can easily only take fields that contain `tagName` that has probability of more than 50%.

Comment: Well, if you *really want* an array, then you can always deserialize an instance of `ResponseJsonNode` and just add it to an array or list.  Of course, that array or list will *always* have exactly one element in it.  So it still doesn't really make sense why you need this.  But nothing is really stopping you.  You're just expecting the JSON serializer to somehow know that you want this, which of course it doesn't.  You'd write code to do this instead.

Comment: So basicaly there is no library to convert json string to separate objects and I have to make a string parser for all of that? Json example response consists of thousands of nodes, its not just only one record as ive shown in my example - it ends with ',' to indicate that there is more than one.

Comment: If the information in the question doesn't represent the actual data you're using, nobody here can help you.  Please update the question to include a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.  Include a usable example of the JSON data (as a string in your C# code, representing the result of your API operation) and the operation(s) you're trying to perform on that data.  Indicate specifically which operation is producing an unexpected result, what result was expected, and why.

Comment: Updated question with sufficient data.

Comment: In that case [your code works](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PhUfFU).  Or at least it does what I expect it to do and, more to the point, does not produce the error described.  Do you have an example which actually produces an error?  What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Solution giving error is:
Actual json: https://pasteboard.co/2sEyR0xz6ZHq.png
Actual Class for handling `List<ResponseJsonNode> jsonNodeList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ResponseJsonNode>>(json);` this code is this: 
```public class ResponseJson {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string project { get; set; }
        public string iteration { get; set; }
        public DateTime created { get; set; }
        public ResponseJsonNode predictions { get; set; }
    } ```
Produced error: `The JSON value could not be converted to Collections.Generic.List`

Comment: This puts us back to the very beginning... The (picture of) JSON to which you link there is an *object* and not an *array*.  You can't deserialize an object into an array because an object is not an array.  It's an object.  You should deserialize your object into an object.  Not an array.

Comment: I might be understanding what's the point here - in second solution which You are probably talking about, that produces error for me and for You not is that I have a `JsonNode` that contains `projectID` field etc. and List of `predictions` - this list I want to have in array. So thats why it gives me an error of `System.InvalidOperationException: The node must be of type 'JsonArray'` because im not doing this operation on `SubNodes`. How to perform this on `SubNodes`?

Comment: The second approach in the question looks like it's just over-complicating the attempt.  I'd abandon that approach unless you have a compelling reason to use it.  The first approach, which is a simple call to `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>()`, will work just fine unless you encounter some kind of performance bottleneck on the volume of data.  The problem, as has been indicated and demonstrated multiple times, is that you're deserializing it into *the wrong type*.  The C# class structure needs to match the JSON structure (or at least a necessary subset of it).

Comment: You are 100% right, sorry for my incompetence in helping You understand my assignment, this was my first encounter with JSON file, yet You helped me a lot. Thank You again, everything works fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Updated from clarification in [this comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74601729/how-do-i-convert-json-string-into-jsonobject-and-iterate-on-it-net-core-6-0-c#comment131684789_74601729).]

The JSON you're showing isn't an array.  Which is why you can't deserialize it into an array.  It's *an object* which *contains* an array.  But in order to access that array you need to deserialize the object.

So deserialize the object.  For example, using this class:

```
public class ResponseObject
{
    public IEnumerable<ResponseJsonNode> predictions { get; set; }
}
```

You can deserialize your object into that class:

```
ResponseJsonNode jsonNode = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponseObject>(json);
```

Basically the problem you're running into is understanding the difference between an object and an array of objects, or an object and a *property on* an object.  You need to understand your data structure(s) in order to use that data.

Comment: No, this is not a single object, if you scroll to the end of it there is a , that indicates more of records being made in this string. I have about 1000 objects with different probabilities and i wan them to sit in array and pick ones that have more than 50%

Comment: @Majkel being picky, the string you have posted is not valid JSON. It is a snippet or fragment. Wrap the whole string in a single array `[ ... ]` or, just parse a single object `{ ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

If your json is literally you shown, you need to modify it a little bit, then deserialize in a standard way.

```
public class ResponseJsonNode {

    public double Probability { get; set; }
    public string TagId { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public BoundingBox BoundingBox { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() =>
        $"[Node]: Probability: {Probability}; TagId: {TagId}; TagName: {TagName};\nBoundingBox: {BoundingBox}";
}

public class BoundingBox
{
    public double Left { get; set; }
    public double Top { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => $"[L:{Left};T:{Top};Width:{Width};Height:{Height}]";
}
```

Deserialize then:

```
var json = GetJsonFromApi();
var trimmedJson = $"[{json.TrimEnd(',')}]";

var collection = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ResponseJsonNode>>(trimmedJson, new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web));

foreach (var item in collection)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item}\n");
}
```

Btw, C# naming convention recommends name properties in a PascalCase, for deserialization from camelCase just use `JsonSerializerDefaults.Web` options.

> and I want to pick only these object that contain probability*100 > 50.

Then simple LINQ filtration comes to the scene.

Comment: @Majkel could it be that your json string has sourrounding brackets `[` and `]` like in this example: `[{...}, {...}, {...}]`  or has the json string no brackets like this `{...}, {...}, {...}` ?